# Brightness Keys Not Working on Lenovo Ideapad 5, Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, brightness, acpi, 21.04

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5 running Ubuntu 21.04. No matter what I do, the brightness keys do not work.

Output of neofetch:

```
OS: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
Host: 82FG IdeaPad 5 15ITL05 
Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic 
Uptime: 9 mins 
Packages: 2401 (dpkg), 11 (flatpak), 6 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.4 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 40.3 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Orchis-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz 
GPU: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
Memory: 3035MiB / 11770MiB
```

Things I have tried/additional information:

- The brightness slider works but ONLY when acpi_backlight=vendor is NOT present in the grub kernel parameters.
- Using acpi_listen shows that no event is even detected when either brightness key is pressed, since pressing either volume button shows an event.
- The ideapad_laptop kernel module is loaded.
- There is no difference when using Wayland or X11, even with an Intel configuration file in X11.
- None of these commands work:

  xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp

  xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown

  xdotool key 232

  xdotool key 233